# HTML/ PHP Group Results by Date

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello maybe someone on here can help me with a bug fix;
I need to group ad results by date starting with the date for now, yesterday and so on...

i.e.

12/30/2015 (todays date)
{results}

12/29/15 (yesterdays date)
{results}

12/28/15
{results}

and so on.....

---

/* THE BUG IS IN HERE .... */

$row[catname] $path_sep $row[subcatname]";} ?>

-

Comment: Do you need a GROUP BY or do you really need an ORDER BY clause? GROUP BY is used for aggregating results (i.e. you are counting all the cars in your table and grouping them by color to count how many you have of each color).

Answer (score -1):

I just need the listings to populate under a unique date for that listing. I believe the answer is Group BY; I need to group all the ad results with the same creation date under the matching date of the date being listed.

Today 12/30/15 
Adid 1 (creation date: 12/30/15)
Adid 22 (creation date: 12/30/15)
Adid 41 (creation date: 12/30/15)
Adid 18 (creation date: 12/30/15)
Adid 16 (creation date: 12/30/15)
Adid 91 (creation date: 12/30/15)
Adid 126 (creation date: 12/30/15)

*** The AdId doesnt have to be ordered just grouped with the rest of the ads under the same date